# Confusion regarding interpretation of a diffusion related PDE?

Tags: particle-physics, biophysics, diffusion

So I was reading [Keller & Segel paper](http://jxshix.people.wm.edu/2013-taiwan/Keller-Segel-1970-JTB.pdf) related to mathematical model of cellular aggregation in slime molds. In the model (considering 2D assumption) we have an equation like below:

$\frac{\partial a}{\partial t} = -\nabla . ( D_1(\nabla\rho)) + \nabla . (D_2(\nabla a) )$

The terms $a$ is the concentration of amoeba cells, $\rho$ is the cAMP concentration, $D_1$ and $D_2$ are the corresponding diffusion coefficients. The amoeba gets attracted towards cAMP( cyclic adenosine monophosphate).

The equation as far as I could interpret is like this : "The rate of change of amoeba concentration in a small area is the difference in flow of cells from higher concentration to lower concentration of amoeba (2nd term) and flow of cells towards higher concentration of cAMP (1st term)".

Here comes 2 doubts:

1. $\nabla a$ is the gradient of $a$ whose directions are towards higher rate of change spatially. But in diffusion the amoeba of higher density flows towards lower density, right? Am I missing something fundamental.
2. This doubt is a general one : What are the implications of the negative diffusion term?

---

**UPDATE** : The complete model is as below :

[image]

Comment: I'm sorry, but I don't know enough biology to say if amoeba can be treated in the same way as inert particles can.  http://chemwiki.ucdavis.edu/Physical_Chemistry/Kinetics/Complex_Reactions/Ionic_Mobility_and_Electrophoresis/Diffusion

Comment: Equations such as these are not fundamental scientific insights but ad-hoc attempts to explain phenomena. If these cells behave this way, at least in some simplified experiments, good for Keller & Segel, if they don't, nothing bad happened. Personally I would venture to guess that the model is too naive and that a more complicated equation that would take the metabolic rates of these cells into account would be better. I also suspect, based on the age of the paper,  that there is some more complex inter-cellular communication going on which is better understood by now, but IANAB.

Comment: I have only shown one equation in the model. There are others too. I am trying to interpret it.